# Choosing 5 days out of 31 to work with only working 1 sunday (out of 5)

Tags: combinatorics

A student needs to work five days in January. He does not want to work on more than one Sunday. In how many ways can he select five working days, assuming there are five sundays this month.

My thought is that you take (31 choose 5) and subtract all the "bad days" off. The bad days are those of which you have more than one sunday. which are sum from k=2 to 5 (5 choose k). Is this a correct way of thinking about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  You can do what you are thinking, but you haven't said how to subtract the "bad days".  An easier approach is to say he has two choices.  He can either work no Sundays-how many ways can he choose the days with no Sundays? Or he can work one Sunday.  Now he picks one Sunday and four other days-how many ways is that?  Now add them together.

Comment: The way I was thinking was to just subtract 31 choose 5 from the sum.

Comment: and would it be (26 choose 5)+5*(27 choose 4)? He has 26 ways to choose 5 non-sunday days and then has (27 choose 4) ways to choose the days that are not sunday and 5 sundays to choose from.

Comment: Exactly.  If you do the same for choosing 2,3,4,5 Sundays you can subtract the sum of that from ${31 \choose 5}$ but it is more work.  You should get the same answer.

Comment: The two answers are slightly off for a reason I can't see

Comment: This is what I did for my first solution:
(31 choose 5)-(5 choose 2) - (5 choose 3) -(5 choose 4)- (5 choose 5)

Comment: For your first solution, it should be ${31 \choose 5}-{5 \choose 2}{26 \choose 3}-{5 \choose 3}{26 \choose 2}-{5 \choose 4}{26 \choose 1}-{5 \choose 5}{26 \choose 0}$ I don't see the choices out of $26$ in your expression.